# Compiling multiple .c and .h files

Tags: c, struct, makefile, compilation, include

My program is divided into 6 files:

1. list.h (Containing basic list struct info and function prototypes)
2. list.c (Containg the implementation of the above)
3. search_tree.h (Containing basic tree struct info and function prototypes)
4. search_tree.c (Containing the implementation of the above, and includes list.h)
5. search.h ( again, prototypes of functions )
6. search.c (implementation of the aobve functions)
7. main.c ( Requires all of the above in order to run )

I cant seem to figure out what the makefile should be, i've tried the one below but it doesnt work and i get errors of structs and functions not implemented.

```
myprog: list.o search_tree.o search.o main.o
    gcc -o myprog list.o search_tree.o search.o main.o

list.o: list.c list.h
    gcc -c list.c

search_tree.o: search_tree.c search_tree.h
    gcc -c search_tree.c

search.o: search.c search.h
    gcc -c search.c

main.o: search.h search_tree.h list.h hash_table.h
   gcc -c main.c
```

Comment: `.h` files are not compiled. And "doesn't work" is not a valid problem description.

Comment: You have two rules for search.o, one of those should be search_tree.o

Comment: you could just type: `gcc -o myprog *.c` if all your files are in the same dir

Comment: @odin yes, my bad while copying the code, im editing it now.

Comment: @EugeneSh. Im not compiling any .h files in my code.Also, i mention what kind of errors i get.

Comment: how are you even sure it's a makefile problem? Have you tried compiling it all manually? If it's complaining it can't find structs it sounds like to me you're forgetting a `#include` somewhere

Comment: You might want to add `-I.` to your `gcc` command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to explicitly create a rule for each file - `make` has a number of [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Using-Implicit) that already do 90% of what you need.  Your makefile can be as simple as

```
CC=gcc
CFLAGS=-std=c11 -pedantic -Wall -Werror # my usual compiler flags
LDFLAGS=   # specify additional libraries and library search paths here

myprog: main.o search.o search_table.o list.o
        $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $?

clean:
        rm -rf myprog *.o
```

There's already an implicit rule to build `.o` files from `.c` files, so you don't need to create your own unless you want to override the default, which is

```
%.o : %.c
        $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

You do need the explicit `myprog` rule to link the object files into the executable since the executable name doesn't match any of the source or object file names.  `$@` expands to the target name, `myprog`, and `$?` expands to the list of prerequisites for the target (i.e., the object files).  `$<` expands to the first name in the list of prerequisites.

This doesn't cover header file dependencies, but your project is small enough for that to not be too much of an issue.  However, give [this article](http://scottmcpeak.com/autodepend/autodepend.html) a read for one way to handle that.

Comment: Great answer, lots of help.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Similar to John's proposal with a small bug fixed (`$^` automatic variable instead of `$?`), a bit more automation (`wildcard` to search for the C source files) and with dependencies added for the header files (`$(OBJS): %.o: %.h` static pattern rule):

```
EXEC := myprog
OBJS := $(patsubst %.c,%.o,$(wildcard *.c))

$(EXEC): $(OBJS)
    $(CC) -o $@ $(LDFLAGS) $^

$(OBJS): %.o: %.h

clean:
    rm -f $(EXEC) $(OBJS)
```